# How to get all pages from Ghost blog platform, using the get helper

Tags: ghost-blog

I am trying to get all pages from ghost blog.

```
{{#get "posts" limit="all" filter="page:true"}}
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on latest Ghost instance (or at least the version that has Content API `^2.10.0`).

You can use `limit=all` attribute to fetch all `page` resouces like so:

```
{{#get "pages" limit="all"}}...{{/get}}
```

You can find more about the `limit` attribute in Ghost Docs for [{{get}}](https://docs.ghost.org/api/handlebars-themes/helpers/get/) helper and page resource [here](https://docs.ghost.org/concepts/pages/)

Comment: it don't get the pages :( I don't know why... maybe the theme is not creating them as a page.. I am using London theme..